# What is the easiest way in Maven pom.xml to upgrade all usages of log4j2 to 2.15.0, including dependencies using log4j2? See CVE-2021-44228

Tags: spring-boot, security, log4j, log4j2, log4shell

A severe security vulnerability was found for log4j2 <= 2.14.1 (see https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44228). How can I update the pom.xml of a Spring Boot application to make sure that all (recursive) usages of log4j2 use version 2.15.0?

Comment: Please check this setting way.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70329703/7235707

Answer (score 5):

#### Updates:

- 2022/01/04:

  > Log4J 2.17.1 contains a fix for [CVE-2021-44832](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44832)
- 2021/12/22:

  > Spring Boot **2.5.8** and **2.6.2** haven been released and provide dependency management for logback 1.2.9 and Log4J 2.17.0.
- [2.17.0](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/changes-report.html#a2.17.0) fixes [CVE-2021-45105](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-45105)
- [2.12.2](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j/2.12.2/pom) released (2021/12/14)
- [2.16.0](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/changes-report.html#a2.16.0) fixes also [CVE-2021-45046](https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot)

---

##### OP:

[spring-boot](/questions/tagged/spring-boot) "by default" is NOT AFFECTED by CVE-2021-44228([log4shell](/questions/tagged/log4shell)).

Though versions `[2 - 2.6.1]` (any `-starter`) depend on `log4j-api` and `slf4j-to-log4j`,
[Slf4j says](http://slf4j.org/log4shell.html):

> If you are using log4j-over-slf4j.jar in conjunction with the SLF4J API, **you are safe unless the underlying implementation is log4j 2.x**.

To be sure,

- in [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) inspect the output of:

  ```
  mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes='*log4j*'
  ```
- in [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle):

  ```
  gradle -q dependencyInsight --dependency log4j
  ```

---

#### Having `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` on board

We are *definitely affected* (with spring-boot > 1)!

To (fix via) update, the easiest is probably:

- maven:

  ```
  <properties>
     ...
    <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version><!-- as of 2021/12/28 -->
  </properties>
  ```

  ..in the pom.
- gradle:

  ```
  ext['log4j2.version'] = '2.17.1'
  ```

  .. in build.gradle, or:

  ```
  log4j2.version=2.17.1
  ```

  .. in gradle.properties.

...build, test, release, deploy.

---

#### Links:

- [log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot](https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot)
- [slf4j-log4shell](http://slf4j.org/log4shell.html)
- [CVE-2021-44228](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44228)
- [CVE-2021-45046](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-45046)
- [CVE-2021-45105](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-45105)

Comment: macos works with command: `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes='*log4j*'`

Answer (score 3):

This will also stipulate spring-boot-starter-log4j2's log4j2 components version.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Following up @Piotr P. Karwasz's recommendation, that's a better setting choice.
Update:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

By the way, If the project's log4j dependencies are only from spring-boot-starter-log4j2, it has a definitive setting way, refer to [spring blog](https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot)

```
<properties>
    <log4j2.version>2.17.0</log4j2.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: The `log4j` artifact sets the version of many other artifacts that are related to Log4j, but are not part of the Log4j Project. In order to manage the version of only the Log4j artifacts, the `log4j-bom` should be used.

Comment: Is log4j totally/binary backward-compatible? in other words, can it be replaced without changing even a single line of code? https://stackoverflow.com/q/70440185/2365724

Answer (score 3):

Now it's recommended to use
`<log4j2.version>2.16.0</log4j2.version>`

Answer (score 2):

Generally for maven projects, you can force log4j-core version with deps mgmt.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

After this, make sure this pom.xml and all inheriting pom.xml do define log4j deps *without  tag* so that they will all benefit from this centralized change.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [apache site](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/index.html), the the minimum acceptable level for log4j is now **2.17.1** - The mitigation is to upgrade to Log4j 2.3.2 (for Java 6), 2.12.4 (for Java 7), or 2.17.1 (for Java 8 and later).