# how to exclude log4j old version

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, log4j2

I have upgraded log4j to 2.17.0 but it is trying to download old version and new version .Have tried to exclude the 2.11.0 version but still is getting to download the old version and new version as well. Can anyone help me please how to exclude the old version .Since I was facing some version compatibility issues I have not upgraded to higher version .So can anyone let me know the reason why it is showing old version still

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>Service</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
        <name>Service</name>
        <description>Project for  Service</description>
    
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <springboot.version>2.1.6.RELEASE</springboot.version>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.0</surefire-plugin.version>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                    <version>${springboot.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.17.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.17.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the easiest way in Maven pom.xml to upgrade all usages of log4j2 to 2.15.0, including dependencies using log4j2? See CVE-2021-44228](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70331597/what-is-the-easiest-way-in-maven-pom-xml-to-upgrade-all-usages-of-log4j2-to-2-15)

Comment: Specifically check [tombear's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70332936/11748454).

Answer (score 0):

Can check if you have added dependencies anywhere else in ur project.
Even I added below code it works perfectly fine for me.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.slf4j.impl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

try adding this lines might help you :)